# The error "Breaks and labels are different lengths" appears when using grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following script:

```
dataset_prices2017 <- read.csv("/home/nasser/Desktop/prices2017.csv")
dataset_prices2018 <- read.csv("/home/nasser/Desktop/prices2018.csv")
dataset_prices2019 <- read.csv("/home/nasser/Desktop/prices2019.csv")

selectedDF <- dataset_prices2017 %>% select(Price, Volume)
plot_17 <- ggplot(selectedDF, aes(Price, Volume)) + geom_hex(bins = 30) + theme_bw() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") + labs(fill = "Count")
plot_17 <- plot_17 + scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(3,"Dark2"), labels = percent(0.25*0:4))

selectedDF <- dataset_prices2018 %>% select(Price, Volume)
plot_18 <- ggplot(selectedDF, aes(Price, Volume)) + geom_hex(bins = 30) + theme_bw() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") + labs(fill = "Count")
plot_18 <- plot_18 + scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(3,"Dark2"), labels = percent(0.25*0:4))

selectedDF <- dataset_prices2019 %>% select(Price, Volume)
plot_19 <- ggplot(selectedDF, aes(Price, Volume)) + geom_hex(bins = 30) + theme_bw() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") + labs(fill = "Count")
plot_19 <- plot_19 + scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(3,"Dark2"), labels = percent(0.25*0:4))

fullPlot <-  grid.arrange(plot_17, plot_18, plot_19, ncol=3, nrow = 1)
```

Running this script generates the following error:

```
Error in f(..., self = self) : Breaks and labels are different lengths
```

Note that I got this error after adding the last line in the script.

Do you have any idea how to solve this error?

Just figured out that the problem is caused by the data of `plot_18`. The data for that plot:

```
structure(list(Price = c(0.5219551282, 0, 0, 0.194543297766667, 
0.46875, 0.8108108108, 0.2962962963, 0.436213991763333, 0, 0.1904761905, 
0.0208333333, 0, 0, 0.630769230766667, 0.0074626866, 0, 0.7037037037, 
0.70736842106, 0.597250859103333, 0.88, 0.6666666667, 0, 0.13523391815, 
0.035490830643333, 0.02705627708, 0.0666666667, 0.29674796745, 
0.41944444446, 0.1621621622, 0.09127725854, 0.9234567901, 0.582170542623333, 
0.28962962964, 0.79312169317, 0.793380614656667, 0.875187969906667, 
0.03595113442, 0.113242009126667, 0.0293040293, 0.381194511696667, 
0.0344827586, 0.09544715448, 0.161734693876667, 0.123095238113333, 
0.7075949367, 0, 0.8125, 0.8571428571, 0.9, 0.9333333333, 0.79920634921, 
0.0085106383, 0.713333333323333, 0.62150537635, 0.232905982933333, 
0.868, 0.851580459763333, 0.743589743583333, 0.744298245626667, 
0, 0.434379671133333, 0.797916666666667, 0.2222222222, 0.612962962953333, 
0.591333333333333, 0.516666666666667, 0.53809523808, 0.611515151526667, 
0.64246575339, 0.7101449275, 0.122445561153333, 0.65848765432, 
0.2558526441, 0.641025641, 0.347892720293333, 0.0769230769, 0.353939393936667, 
0.978333333333333, 0.755238095256667, 0.863333333333333, 0.6751243781, 
0.67297297298, 0.5344017094, 0.0057142857, 0.921568627463333, 
0.52644927536, 0.128333333333333, 0, 0.1904761905, 0.471929824536667, 
0.15972222225, 0, 0, 0, 0.446258503403333, 0.44210526318, 0.82189054726, 
0.628169014093333, 0, 0.2307692308, 0.191304347823333, 0.4004385965, 
0.83441734419, 0.20449172577, 0.746598639443333, 0.211494252846667, 
0.8695652174, 0.519999999993333, 0.113333333333333, 0.637142857133333, 
0.699420289853333, 0.7391304348, 0.457575757543333, 0.461904761866667, 
0.788888888883333, 0.503065134103333, 0.499616858236667, 0.793888888883333, 
0.70901542112, 0.591358024693333, 0.47769028871, 0.456692913383333, 
0.40625, 0, 0.7678571429, 0.796969696963333, 0.914886731406667, 
0.102424242446667, 0.487804878, 0.1923076923, 0, 0.3658536585, 
0.634782608673333, 0.385028248613333, 0.69864864864, 0.60404040406, 
0.814880952386667, 0.533582089543333, 0.8695652174, 0, 0.715942029016667, 
0.74987277353, 0.864455782326667, 0.624999999986667, 0.3333333333, 
0.4642857143, 0.10434782606, 0.078095238096667, 0.0119047619, 
0.427472527466667, 0.0909090909, 0.6071428571, 0.6071428571, 
0.064516129, 0.500266666666667, 0.5263157895, 0, 0.75256410254, 
0.691836734676667, 0.2083333333, 0.5, 0.85625, 0.6666666667, 
0.60065359476, 0.5, 0.279012345676667, 0.1176470588, 0.5185185185, 
0.8085106383, 0.5365853659, 0.9090909091, 0.82589928058, 0, 0, 
0.03175438598, 0.511764705856667, 0.0196078431, 0.693650793643333, 
0.18378378382, 0.10596205961, 0.022916666666667, 0.288888888903333, 
0.306666666673333, 0, 0.68078703703, 0.744217687073333, 0.6428571429, 
0.828462709286667, 0.887265917566667, 0.713710691823333, 0.76077643908, 
0.72816091955, 0.648370927326667, 0.76565656568, 0.315458937203333, 
0.29583333335, 0.714765100693333, 0.812159329126667, 0.05, 0.713681592026667, 
0.10976645433, 0.75625, 0, 0.42777777777, 0.6842105263, 0.79678362574, 
0.71025641027, 0.88205128204, 0.84959349595, 0.650104821806667, 
0.9032258065, 0.895652173936667, 0.374390243886667, 0.531182795713333, 
0.8429378531, 0.08, 0.030075188, 0, 0.0134228188, 0.93787878788, 
0.7804878049, 0.556666666676667, 0.506630824373333, 0, 0.368527918786667, 
0.7439716312, 0.21818181816, 0.7647058824, 0.90188034188, 0.792857142846667, 
0.157142857183333, 0.19814814816, 0.799047619056667, 0.8947368421, 
0, 0.318562091513333, 0.40884353743, 0.085815602833333, 0.14280701756, 
0.804624277473333, 0.5714285714, 0.867759562826667, 0.624074074063333, 
0.24139784949, 0.42, 0.716269841283333, 0.692539109493333, 0.398290598286667, 
0.474193548386667, 0.5384615385, 0.225925925923333, 0.1666666667, 
0.156540084396667, 0.6666666667, 0.82459546925, 0.683681592026667, 
0.70945945945, 0.677494692146667, 0.65738396624, 0.83459119496, 
0.794179894193333, 0.533630952366667, 0.639999999996667, 0.620648967546667, 
0.301428571416667, 0.10307017545, 0.72935323382, 0.43850129199, 
0.43074712644, 0.432835820883333, 0.1666666667, 0.668965517236667, 
0.062745098026667, 0.625, 0.0425531915, 0.617567567546667, 0.069005847956667, 
0.081836327346667, 0.6956521739, 0.9818181818, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4324324324, 
0.2666666667, 0.2857142857, 0, 0.4027777778, 0.71195402298, 0.64342105263, 
0.7741935484, 0.186419753086667, 0.822710622716667, 0, 0, 0.021875, 
0.091484184913333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6666666667, 0.737435897473333, 
0.759420289843333, 0.6666666667, 0.295928753186667, 0.75420054203, 
0.039602925803333, 0.6666666667, 0.183333333326667, 0.74521072797, 
0.43983739835, 0.653645833333333, 0, 0.1935483871, 0.22883895131, 
0.72955465589, 0.380459770086667, 0.844061302676667, 0.952873563223333, 
0.3325), Volume = c(0.002414102564097, 0.001174398625467, 
0.0010256410256, 0.001051838671393, 0.002878125, 0.004077477477493, 
0.00177037037037, 0.003053909465023, 0.00206551724138, 0.002257142857167, 
0.002033333333333, 0.001, 0.001072380952367, 0.0029717948718, 
0.002232587064677, 0.00201036414567, 0.0021, 0.00292771929824, 
0.003005841924393, 0.008772666666667, 0.002482539682533, 0.0016028328612, 
0.001884795321637, 0.001899568500543, 0.001675757575777, 0.0012, 
0.002775880758787, 0.002668333333327, 0.00151171171169, 0.001388785046723, 
0.00607530864197, 0.00415348837209, 0.002834814814827, 0.008986243386227, 
0.0020964539007, 0.005417543859647, 0.00207905759162, 0.002877168949767, 
0.001929792429827, 0.003026553672313, 0.00150344827588, 0.001880108401087, 
0.001844047619057, 0.002190952380963, 0.00348396624472, 0.0010344827586, 
0.006220833333333, 0.00308730158726, 0.002998333333333, 0.00227777777778, 
0.002014484126987, 0.00126765957446, 0.003718888888883, 0.005132616487453, 
0.002628205128203, 0.004248, 0.007026293103447, 0.002628205128207, 
0.003443421052633, 0.001, 0.002645739910313, 0.008983333333333, 
0.0017777777778, 0.002870370370367, 0.003363333333333, 0.00210256410256, 
0.003542857142857, 0.002534848484847, 0.00231506849313, 0.002258454106293, 
0.001163484087093, 0.005761111111113, 0.00211039809863, 0.002683760683757, 
0.016383908045983, 0.002228205128207, 0.00215212121213, 0.004805, 
0.010981904761907, 0.00828875, 0.00274427860695, 0.002558108108107, 
0.002019444444443, 0.0015914285714, 0.004362745098053, 0.002043840579703, 
0.002366666666667, 0.001103703703693, 0.001742857142873, 0.004219298245603, 
0.00166712962963, 0.001, 0.0013430107527, 0.0015434782609, 0.002538775510207, 
0.003559899749367, 0.0025592039801, 0.00343615023474, 0.001239955849933, 
0.002176923076903, 0.001110144927567, 0.00341403508773, 0.003459349593493, 
0.002460283687937, 0.00319863945578, 0.00226666666666, 0.018426086956527, 
0.003018888888873, 0.002331666666667, 0.003414285714283, 0.002526956521737, 
0.00519710144927, 0.002732034632027, 0.002861904761897, 0.003106666666673, 
0.002896934865907, 0.00257969348659, 0.003066111111117, 0.00349881376038, 
0.00244814814815, 0.00230262467191, 0.002416272965877, 0.00248125, 
0.001801666666667, 0.007639880952377, 0.002253030303033, 0.009329126213587, 
0.00166909090911, 0.00293821138211, 0.004464102564097, 0.002315942029033, 
0.003039024390237, 0.015501449275363, 0.008321468926553, 0.009915315315317, 
0.004964646464643, 0.00526488095237, 0.004199004975113, 0.00949130434782, 
0.001162745098033, 0.00265942028985, 0.002461323155213, 0.013436054421777, 
0.003893253968247, 0.001716666666667, 0.00195595238097, 0.0019130434783, 
0.001076190476233, 0.001866269841277, 0.003128937728933, 0.0021, 
0.00230238095237, 0.00248333333332, 0.00281397849465, 0.002320533333333, 
0.002299122807017, 0.002, 0.00275, 0.002816326530617, 0.002254166666667, 
0.00369761904762, 0.00381875, 0.003125925925927, 0.005600000000007, 
0.00369861111111, 0.002507407407373, 0.0014117647059, 0.003214814814817, 
0.002590070921973, 0.00297479674797, 0.01804242424242, 0.00463980815348, 
0.001, 0.0010222222222, 0.001853947368427, 0.0017058823529, 0.0011568627451, 
0.003668253968263, 0.00215675675675, 0.001922222222237, 0.002383333333333, 
0.00296495726495, 0.04700512820514, 0.001080952380933, 0.007685648148143, 
0.0026112244898, 0.014720238095237, 0.00248949771689, 0.00493520599251, 
0.00640553459119, 0.004878313253013, 0.00365545977011, 0.004275689223057, 
0.01131245791246, 0.003004106280193, 0.00678472222223, 0.005784004474273, 
0.004531446540867, 0.001835, 0.00332611940299, 0.001566454352443, 
0.01443125, 0.001049275362333, 0.007142424242427, 0.0240552631579, 
0.007115204678353, 0.003953846153853, 0.00365705128204, 0.005986720867213, 
0.002818448637317, 0.00557311827956, 0.00247934782609, 0.002582926829263, 
0.003732258064523, 0.00645706214689, 0.004855999999993, 0.001249122807027, 
0.0010241545894, 0.00103154362418, 0.013604545454543, 0.005505691056917, 
0.002934444444437, 0.002545340501793, 0.0010238095238, 0.00221370558375, 
0.00335000000001, 0.001788552188527, 0.00236274509804, 0.013679487179487, 
0.005909523809527, 0.003596190476187, 0.002676851851847, 0.00611942857143, 
0.005988596491227, 0.002, 0.002481045751637, 0.00392789115644, 
0.00167568389058, 0.002203684210527, 0.003684778420043, 0.0097238095238, 
0.00281311475409, 0.003364074074077, 0.002609677419357, 0.002558, 
0.002856746031737, 0.00735330926595, 0.001780128205137, 0.00261075268818, 
0.002848717948717, 0.00189058641975, 0.001945555555547, 0.001983966244727, 
0.005273333333327, 0.004203883495147, 0.003079104477617, 0.003092342342337, 
0.003043312101907, 0.00304556962024, 0.003135220125783, 0.004403703703707, 
0.002158333333327, 0.004803902439023, 0.00234247787612, 0.0019919047619, 
0.001954385964913, 0.003713432835827, 0.002959173126613, 0.00378965517242, 
0.00259552238807, 0.002186111111113, 0.001156704980857, 0.002354901960793, 
0.01525625, 0.0015957446809, 0.00489594594594, 0.001830409356733, 
0.00169753825682, 0.00253671497585, 0.01430363636364, 0.0025, 
0.016829166666667, 0.002627027027023, 0.002300000000033, 0.0022857142857, 
0.002, 0.001732870370397, 0.002788850574713, 0.00302105263158, 
0.008280645161293, 0.002154938271587, 0.003345421245423, 0.001345662100463, 
0.001486666666667, 0.00210078125, 0.002824574209243, 0.001466666666667, 
0.002, 0.002, 0.001147619047633, 0.00367654320988, 0.00385538461539, 
0.003284541062797, 0.00693765432099, 0.001989058524173, 0.004204607046073, 
0.002009299895507, 0.004667777777773, 0.00320292397661, 0.003397318007663, 
0.00231788617884, 0.005576388888893, 0.001764102564133, 0.002895698924767, 
0.001935205992517, 0.002502699055333, 0.002919540229867, 0.00350996168583, 
0.003030459770113, 0.002411666666667)), .Names = c("Price", 
"Volume"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -320L
))
```

When I remove the `labels = percent(0.25*0:4)`, the error is gone. However, I added this in order to show the legend labels as `25%, 50%, 75%, 100%`. What should I do to solve this issue? It's important for me to show the legend labels as I mentioned.

Comment: Just try removing `3` from `brewer.pal(3,"Dark2")` as you're extracting 3 colors but passing 5 labels with `percent(0.25*0:4)`

Comment: You need to give the same number of colors as say PoGibas than the number of labels. Is it to say 5.

Comment: Number of legend labels doesn't match number of breaks you specify.

Comment: The colors are according to the count of Observations. What would you like to color to? Are the other plots working for you, when you plot them separately? How is the data of `plot_18` different from the others?
It can be fixed by adding `breaks=0:4*0.25` to the `scale_fill_gradientn()` but I guess the resulting plot is not what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing what your labels indicate are the quantiles of counts. So first let's get back what your original plot is without percentage labels:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)
library(RColorBrewer)

plot_17 <- ggplot(selectedDF, aes(Price, Volume)) + 
geom_hex(bins = 30) + theme_bw() +
geom_smooth(method="lm") + labs(fill = "Count")

plot_17_count <- plot_17 + 
scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(3,"Dark2"))
```

The problem with defining a 0,0.25.. labels for every plot is, you might have different number of breaks depending on the range. You can see for the plot above (plot_17_count), it has only 3 breaks. For you to place the percentiles correctly, you need to access the hexbin count inside geom_hex.. which might not be so easy. One workaround is to transform the scale.

We define the quantiles you need, and a transformation

```
BR = percent(0.25*0:4)
# unfortunately no inverse, I just put in identity so the function works
min_max_trans = trans_new("min_max",function(i)i/(max(i)-min(i)),inverse=identity)

plot_17_perc <- plot_17 + 
scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(3,"Dark2"),
trans=min_max_trans,labels=percent(0.25*0:4))
```

Put them together:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plot_17_count,plot_17_perc)
```

[image]